# Reduce memory usage of application deployed in Heroku

Tags: java, angularjs, heroku, jhipster

I've deployed a spring boot application (Jhipster generated) on Heroku. Currently I'm using free `hobby-dev` account. Free `dyno` type has `Memory(RAM) 512MB`. There is no scope of upgrading my account. How can reduce memory usage of my application?

```
2016-06-18T16:35:00.699291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)    
2016-06-18T16:35:20.823199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=539M(105.0%)
2016-06-18T16:35:20.823289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Comment: Do you tested your app to see, which part is consuming more memory? maybe you need to refactor a bit your code to save memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decrease your max heap size by running this command:

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx300m"
```

For more information see the [Heroku Java documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support).